# evaluating $\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+16}\;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I find
$$\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+16} \;\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried a tangent-based substitution, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: If you are going to use tangent substitution, how have you setup the substitution? $x=...$

Comment: x/4 = tan(t), x= 4tan(t), dx= 4sec^2(t)

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is integration by parts, with the first factor x/2 an the second, well, the rest of it, starting with 2x... (sorry, no teX yet) Or was the tan substitution a requirement of the exercise?

Answer (score 7):

Since the integrand is a *rational* function of $x$ and $\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}$, $a=4$,
the two standard substitutions are:

1. the *trigonometric* substitution $x=a\tan t$
2. the *hyperbolic* substitution $x=a\sinh t$

For 1. use the trigonometric identity
\begin{equation*}
1+\tan ^{2}t=\sec ^{2}t.
\end{equation*}

For 2. use the hyperbolic identity
\begin{equation*}
1+\sinh ^{2}t=\cosh ^{2}t.
\end{equation*}

The 3rd. standard substitution is an *algebraic* one, the *[Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)*

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{x^{2}+16}=x+t\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{16-t^{2}}{2t},\qquad dx=-\frac{
16+t^{2}}{2t^{2}}dt,
\end{equation*}

which reduces the given integral in $x$ to an integral of a *rational* function in $t$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+16}\,dx &=&-\int \left( \frac{16-t^{2}}{2t}\right)
^{2}\left( \frac{16-t^{2}}{2t}+t\right) \frac{16+t^{2}}{2t^{2}}dt,\qquad t= \sqrt{
x^{2}+16}-x \\
&=&-\int \frac{4096}{t^{5}}-\frac{32}{t}+\frac{1}{16}t^{3}dt \\
&=&\frac{1024}{t^{4}}+32\ln |t|-\frac{t^{4}}{64}+C \\
&=&\frac{1024}{\left( \sqrt{x^{2}+16}-x\right) ^{4}}+32\ln \left| \sqrt{
x^{2}+16}-x\right| -\frac{\left( \sqrt{x^{2}+16}-x\right) ^{4}}{64}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}

---

ADDED. I assume that the tangent substitution you mention in the question is
\begin{equation*}
x=4\tan t\Leftrightarrow t=\arctan \frac{x}{4},\qquad dx=(4+4\tan^2 t)dt=4\sec^2 t\,dt,
\end{equation*}

which using the trigonometric identity written above gives

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+16}\,dx &=&\int 16\left( \tan ^{2}t\right) \sqrt{16\tan
^{2}t+16}\left( 4+4\tan ^{2}t\right) \,dt \\
&=&16\times 4\times 4\int \left( \tan ^{2}t\right) \sqrt{\tan ^{2}t+1}\left(
1+\tan ^{2}t\right) \,dt \\
&=&256\int \tan ^{2}t\sec ^{3}t\,dt \\
&=&256\int \frac{\sin ^{2}t}{\cos ^{5}t}\,dt.
\end{eqnarray*}

The integrand is a *rational* function of $\sin t,\cos t$ which is integrable
by the *[Weirstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)*
\begin{equation*}
u=\tan \frac{t}{2},\qquad dt=\frac{2}{\left( 1+u^{2}\right) }\,du.
\end{equation*}

Since
\begin{equation*}
\sin t=\frac{2u}{1+u^{2}},\qquad \cos t=\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}},
\end{equation*}
we obtain

\begin{eqnarray*}
256\int \frac{\sin ^{2}t}{\cos ^{5}t}\,dt &=&256\int \frac{\left( \frac{2u}{
1+u^{2}}\right) ^{2}}{\left( \frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}\right) ^{5}}\frac{2}{
\left( 1+u^{2}\right) }\,du,\qquad u=\tan \frac{t}{2} \\
&=&512\int \frac{4u^{6}+8u^{4}+4u^{2}}{\left( 1-u\right) ^{5}\left(
1+u\right) ^{5}}du.
\end{eqnarray*}

Finally we expand the integrand into partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{4u^{6}+8u^{4}+4u^{2}}{\left( 1-u\right) ^{5}\left( 1+u\right) ^{5}}
&=&-\frac{1}{2\left( u-1\right) ^{5}}-\frac{3}{4\left( u-1\right) ^{4}}-
\frac{3}{8\left( u-1\right) ^{3}}-\frac{1}{16\left( u-1\right) ^{2}}+\frac{1
}{16\left( u-1\right) } \\
&&+\frac{1}{2\left( 1+u\right) ^{5}}-\frac{3}{4\left( 1+u\right) ^{4}}+\frac{
3}{8\left( 1+u\right) ^{3}}-\frac{1}{16\left( 1+u\right) ^{2}}-\frac{1}{
16\left( 1+u\right) }.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use the substitution $x=4\sinh(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

As AméricoTavares has found $$\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+16}dx=256\int\tan^2t\sec^3tdt$$

Now, $\displaystyle\tan^2t\sec^3t=(\sec^2t-1)\sec^3t=\sec^5t-\sec^3t$

Now use the [reduction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant)([proof](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=10932)) of $\displaystyle\int\sec^nt\ dt$ and the terminating case being [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function)

Again as $\displaystyle x=4\tan t\implies t=\arctan\frac x4,$ using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) , $\displaystyle-\frac\pi2\le t\le \frac\pi2\implies\sec t>0$ and $\sec t=+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac x4\right)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int x^2\mathrm {\sqrt{x^2+16}}dx$$$$=\int(x^2+16-16)\mathrm {\sqrt{x^2+16}} dx$$$$=\int(x^2+16)\mathrm {\sqrt{x^2+16}}dx-\int16\mathrm {\sqrt{x^2+16}}dx$$$$=\int\mathrm {(x^2+16)}^{\frac{3}{2}}dx-\int 16\mathrm {\sqrt{x^2+16}}.dx$$On solving we get$$I=\frac{1024}{\left( \sqrt{x^{2}+16}-x\right) ^{4}}+32\ln \left| \sqrt{
x^{2}+16}-x\right| -\frac{\left( \sqrt{x^{2}+16}-x\right) ^{4}}{64}+C.
$$